# htaccess Rewrite Rule not working without index.php in url

Tags: .htaccess

I am using apache2 in ubuntu m/c. I have enabled mod_rewrite and changed Allowoveride All in apache2.conf

Now I am trying to install Bug-Genie application in my server
But following .htaccess rules are not work as excepted.

**I can access :**

```
http://localhost/roxsoft/thebuggenie-3.2.6/thebuggenie/**index.php**/wiki
```

**But I can't access :       --404 error**

```
http://localhost/roxsoft/thebuggenie-3.2.6/thebuggenie/wiki
```

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
# .htaccess file for The Bug Genie

# make sure that magic_quotes and register_globals is always off
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc   off
    php_flag register_globals   off
</IfModule>

# rewrite rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
# Example:
# RewriteBase /
# or
# RewriteBase /dev/thebuggenie

  # skip all hidden files (starting with a .)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(html|wsdl|json|xml)$
  RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # redirect to front controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

</IfModule>
# Stop people accessing directories they shouldn't have access to
RedirectMatch 403 ^/\.svn(/|$)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Add the folder which contains the JavaScript and CSS to the rewrite condition

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.. your code works fine but I need to filter assert files like css, js, images etc... With your code every URL gets  rewritten with index.php/****

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I just managed it with. This may help if anyone had a same problem...

I just removed

and added additional conditions in htaccess
here is it:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(html|wsdl|json|xml)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|css|js|php|gif|ttf|woff)$   ---- ADD FILTER CONDITION.
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]                                              ---- COMMENT THIS LINE************

  # redirect to front controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```